# Install latest version of MongoDB on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, mongodb

I would like to install the latest version of MongoDB on my rpi 3 but `apt-get install` the version 2.4.

How can I install the latest?

Comment: What do you define as "the latest" version? The latest one in a RPi repository? The bleeding-edge development version somewhere in github-land? Some other version?

Answer (score 1):

You need a 64bit OS, So copy that to your sdcard first.

- [bionic-server-arm64.squashfs](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/bionic-server-arm64.squashfs)
- [Fedora-Server-27-1.6.aarch64.raw.xz](http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-secondary/releases/27/Server/aarch64/images/Fedora-Server-27-1.6.aarch64.raw.xz)
- [ArchLinuxARM-aarch64-latest.tar.gz](http://archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-aarch64-latest.tar.gz)
- etc

Then you can install(**3.2**) from a repository

```
apt show mongodb-server 2>/dev/null | grep Version
Version: 1:3.2.11-2+deb9u1
```

or install(**3.6**) from source;

```
apt install git python-pip
mkdir /opt/mongodb
cd /opt/mongodb
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/scons/scons-3.0.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf scons-3.0.1.tar.gz
cd scons-3.0.1
python setup.py install
cd ../
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git --branch v3.6
cd mongo
pip install -r buildscripts/requirements.txt
scons-3.0.1 core MONGO_VERSION=3.6.0-$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
scons-3.0.1 install
```

Comment: What do I need to copy on my sdcard?

Comment: Which OS do you recommend me to take?

Comment: Yes, the latest Raspbian is armv7l, so a 32 bit.

Comment: I don’t know if this is the start of an answer, but it certainly doesn’t include installing the latest mongodb...

Comment: There is 32-bit mongodb, only its maximal db size is limited to 32 bits.

Comment: @kamal951  answer updated. 2 OSs linked

Comment: @roaima  answer updated.

Comment: @JeffSchaller answer updated.

Comment: @peterh answer updated, link a build if you have one but I have not seen a 32bit arm ppa that is maintained.